# How to scroll an element vertically center in view port using java script executor in web using selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm using selenium-web driver and recently came to a halt when trying to click some elements on browsers.When trying to click an element that is out of view port, the page scrolls and places the element at the top of the page.I am looking for scrolling the element to the center of the view port using java script execute script.

Comment: Java != Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(`(JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: \"center\"});", element);`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If this answer works, please explain why. Otherwise it's possible this will get voted down as not useful enough.

Answer (score -1):

You can scroll page by using Javascript executor try this:

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)BrowserUtilities.driver;
```

For top to down:

```
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,200)", "");
```

and

For Left to right:

```
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(200,0)", "");
```

Comment: None of these answer the OP's question. Please read the question again.

Comment: I am aware of scroll for top or scroll to bottom of the page..I have a scenario where I need to click on element but footer note is blocked the view. So scrolling to top is not going to work, as on the top of the page some more headers obstructing the view, only solution is  it has to be at the vertical center...

Comment: Please read comment of JeffC and explain what you have done in your script properly. Also add your research and code you have done till now. If you are not able to explain what you are doing and problem encountered then it will be difficult to help you out.

Answer (score -1):

For full body scroll try this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
     .executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

Scroll to spcfic element try this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("your Locator"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

Scroll to specific coordinates

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)");
```

Comment: None of these answer the OP's question. Please read the question again.